# What is the difference bw using $this->somevariable and somevariable while using to store a newly created object in php

Tags: php, oop

Can someone please explain the difference bw the following two code snippets written in php ? 
One uses $this->task and the other simply $tasks to store the object.

```
 class Foo
{
public $tasks;

function doStuff()
{
    $this->tasks = new Tasks();
    $this->tasks->test();
}

}
```

vs

```
class Foo
{
public $tasks;

function doStuff()
{
    $tasks = new Tasks();
    $tasks->test();
}

}
```

Comment: best thing is to get a good book on oop with PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When not using $this, you are using a local variable that will disappear when function doStuff is finished. When you use $this, the variable will disappear when an instance of class Foo is gone.

**method 1**

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->doStuff();
echo $foo->tasks  --  tasks will be a new instance of Tasks
```

**method 2**

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->doStuff();
echo $foo->tasks  --  tasks will be NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one makes the `Tasks` object a property of the class `Foo`.  You would be able to access it outside of the function.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

In the second, you are creating a variable to holds the object and its scope is only the method of the class.  It is not accessible outside of the method.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `Tasks` from `Foo` outside of the class use `this`. Otherwise it can only be accessed in `doStuff()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the second snippet, the $tasks variable should not be access able in other functions, as you didn't set the object property but just a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

in the first one you use the class variable $tasks but in the second one you create a new variable that is local to function doStuff()

Answer (score 0):

You can't access class variables without using the `$this` keyword in PHP.

Using plain variable name will mean it's local to that function, unlike other programming languages like Java where it will try outer level scopes if it doesn't find the variable name in the current scope.